# Alt text for many images

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, cs6, accessibility

In my InDesign CS6 document, I want to make more accessible by adding Alt text attributes to all the image elements in the document. Some pages have multiple, separate images set up in a collection/collage that are described by the same caption.

For these pages, I tried making a parent element, giving it an Alt attribute and then nesting all the image elements in it, but it does not get picked up by the screen reader once exported as an interactive PDF.

Do I have to just give all the images their own Alt tags for this to work?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've never tried this, so I have no idea. But are you sure the screen reader will pick up the alt text even if properly formatted? Did you check to make sure they're embedded properly? To verify this, I'd try the following: "[_This alternate text information can then be used when the PDF file is saved from Adobe Acrobat® software as an HTML or XML file._](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/indesign/alt-text.html)"

Comment: I followed your linked and verified that they're embedded properly, which is very good to know. After exporting to a PDF, using the read along makes it read the same alt text for those tags, even when I put them all within a parent element. So the reader would say "Figure 1..., Figure 1...., Figure 1...." etc.